# Managing the caching in G-WAN with KV store

Tags: c, web-applications, webserver, g-wan

I am currently developing a web app in C using the G-Wan web server and I want to use the KV Store included with G-Wan in order to store the generated web page and a counter on the number of times the page has been displayed.

The KV store is a hash map you can use to store complex data, like structures.

That's what I have used to store the HTML data and an integer which is the counter:

```
typedef struct
{    
  char* HTML;    
  int nbDisplays;    

} my_data;
```

The web server is using several threads and the KV store is shared among the threads.

For updating the field nbDisplays I am using an atomic operation __sync_fetch_and_add (...)
But I don't know what is the best way to update the field HTML which is a pointer.

Is it better:

1. to build a new structure using the existing one stored in KV to get the current values and add it to the KV Store with the add() function provided by G-WAN (this function replace the old structure by the new one)
2. Or to update directly the values of the structure stored in the KV store?

I am not used to program in a multi thread environment and I am scared about some "strange" behaviors...

Comment: No reply at all... Nobody uses this web server?

Answer (score 1):

`kv_add()` is documented as being an atomic operation. You could use it to update your counter but this is slower than just using an atomic operation to increment the `nbDisplays` counter **without touching the HTML pointer** (the name of the page does not change).

But G-Wan KV Store's features does not make this look like a `hash map`. You can't do those range queries with a `hash map`.

Comment: OK thank you for the reply.

I experience some problems with the counter:
I have used CURL to ask 10 times the same page, first call is made without KV and after the 9 other calls are made using KV and incrementing nbDisplays.
At the end nbDisplays=6 instead of 10.
I don't understand why.

If you have a clue I am interested.

Jérôme

Comment: The source code (explicitly) warns that you should do an atomic incr of the counter. That's exactly why you have threading issues.