# What KV store to chosse with a multi thread web server?

Tags: c, web-applications, webserver

I am developping a web application on G-WAN server which is a multi thread web server.
I don't have enough information about using the KV store available with G-WAN in a multi thread environment and the G-WAN forum is closed to post a question...
That's why I am looking for an other fast KV store developped for being used in a multi thread environment. The value size will be small, less than 20KB.
Do you know a fast KV store for dealing with data with a size less than 20KB very quickly?
I have heard about memcached, REDIS, Tokyo Cabinet... but which one is best for multi thread environment and for storing small data size?

In fact I want to store in the KV store the URL as the key and for the value associated the HTML data and a counter of number of times the HTML data has been displayed.
I just want to be sure that the counter will be incremented correctly in a multi thread environment, if possible without using mutex and others things to manage possible concurrent accesses to the same data at the same time.

If you have any experience of using a KV store in a multi thread environment can you share your experience please?

Thank you
Jérôme

Comment: Do you need the storage to be permanent, or are you only using it for temporary data?

Comment: I suggest that you have a look at atomic instructions - that's the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

For something small and simple I would personally consider using old-fashioned [GDBM](http://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/). While not thread-safe itself, it is small, simple and fast enough, especially for small amounts of data. Adding thread-safety should be simple with wrapper functions that block with a simple semaphore.

Comment: I forgot to speak about the amount of data stored.
The number of records stored will be around 100 000.

Answer (score 0):

Your question about G-Wan's KV Store [has been answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12006364/managing-the-caching-in-g-wan-with-kv-store/12062320#12062320).

The advantage as compared to a `lock` like the suggested `semaphore` for `GDBM` is that G-Wan's KV Store will never be blocking while a thread holds a lock: there's no lock.